# Difference between fsurf and ezsurf - MATLAB bug report

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization

I have a problem with **fsurf** command:

When I use

```
fsurf(@(x,y) ackleyfcn([x,y]),[-32 32 -32 32])
```

I got this warning:

**Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments.**

And this picture (after a long time, about 20 sec):

[fsurf plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yXDW.png)

When I use

```
ezsurf(@(x,y) ackleyfcn([x,y]),[-32 32 -32 32])
```

I got no warning and the correct (and fast) picture:

[ezsurf plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5G0a.png)

Where:

```
function z = ackleyfcn(xx)

% Ackley's function

% Search domain: [-32,32]
% Global minimum: f(x) = 0 | x = (0,...,0)

d = size(xx, 2);
xx = max(-32,min(32,xx));

z = -20*exp(-0.2*sqrt(1/d*sum(xx.^2,2))) - exp(1/d*sum(cos(2*pi*xx),2)) + 20 + exp(1);

end
```

I think this **Ackley's function** is correctly vectorized. Am I right?

What is the error with **fsurf** and why the image generated by it is strange and takes longer to be generated?

Thanks in advance!

*Ps.: I am using **R2017b** version.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html):

> The function must accept two matrix input arguments and return a matrix output argument of the same size.

You assumed that the inputs are column vectors.

To fix this you could try

```
function z = ackleyfcn(x,y)
xx = [x(:),y(:)];
% ... your code here
z = reshape(z,size(x));
```

and

```
fsurf(@ackleyfcn,[-32 32 -32 32])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CrisLuengo, now the warning doesn't show anymore. But it takes a longer time to display the plot and the resulting image is the same before...

Comment: In the documentation for the `MeshDensity` parameter it says "Number of evaluation points per direction, specified as a number. The default is 35. Because fsurf objects use adaptive evaluation, the actual number of evaluation points is greater."  I guess `fsurf` does more work than `ezsurf`.

Answer (score 1):

**MathWorks' Support Response:**

I have been able to reproduce the slow down that you were experiencing. The **fsurf** function tries to determine what density of points to use in order to give an accurate depiction of the function you pass it. Since the **ackleyfcn** has many small oscillations, **fsurf** decides to use a very dense mesh in order to display it. This feature is not available in **ezsurf** which is why the plots look so different.

The time **fsurf** takes is also much longer because if it displaying many more points. If you would like to use **fsurf** to produce the plot similar to **ezplot**, you can **turn off** the ***AdaptiveMeshDenstity*** feature by using the following line of code:

```
set(fsurf(@(x,y) ackleyfcn([x,y]),[-32 32 -32 32]),'AdaptiveMeshDensity',0,'MeshDensity',60)
```

Note that this will increase the speed of **fsurf** and will produce a plot similar to that of **ezsurf**. However, this new surface uses fewer points and so does not fully represent the **ackleyfcn** function.